# How to drop rows that contain certain value, while maintaining rows with empty values?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following small demo DataFrame in Spark Scala:

```
Type   Description
0      
1      Action 1
1      Drop: Action 1
2      Action2
```

I need to drop all rows that contain "Drop" in `Description` column, while maintaining rows with empty `Description`.

Expected result:

```
Type   Description
0      
1      Action 1
2      Action2
```

If I run the code shown below, I get this output (the row with empty `Description` is deleted).

```
Type   Description
1      Action 1
2      Action2
```

My code:

```
df
  .na.fill("Description", Seq("Error"))
  .filter(!(col("Description").contains("Drop")))
  .select(col("Type"),col("Description"))
  .distinct
  .sort(col("Type").asc)
  .show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters you provided for [`na.fill`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions@fill(value:String,cols:Seq[String]):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) are incorrect.  If you look at the signature of the method you're using:

```
def fill(value: String, cols: Seq[String]): DataFrame
```

The "first parameter" is the `value` that replaces a `null` column and "the second parameter" is a `list of columns` for `null`-replacement.  Hence, replacing your `na.fill` code line with the following would work as intended:

```
na.fill("Error", Array("Description"))
```